# Range Error with mongo doing a $near lookup

Tags: javascript, mongodb, geojson

Experiencing a weird error with mongo doing a `$near` lookup. The DB just goes crazy and spits our a range error.

This code snippet below works perfectly fine

```
mongoose.models.Users.findOne({_id: req.user.id}, function(err, loggedin) {
    var location = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(loggedin.location));
    mongoose.models.Users.find({
      location: { $near: { $geometry: location } },
    }, (err, users) => {

    })
})
```

However, if I tallk out the JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) clone it freaks out

```
mongoose.models.Users.findOne({_id: req.user.id}, function(err, loggedin) {
    var location = loggedin.location;
    mongoose.models.Users.find({
      location: { $near: { $geometry: location } },
    }, (err, users) => {

    })
})
```

Using mongoose as you see but that shouldnt effect this query. 
There must be something extra in `location` that I cant see but I cant find it.

If I console.log `loggedin.location` immediately after the DB query I  get this:

```
location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ -118.3141928, 34.0806176 ] },
```

I've also set a debug breakpoint and get the same thing

One other fact thats interesting to note, if I execute the `findOne` query with `lean()` so it only returns plain JSON then the second query works perfectly. I'm wondering if theres some getter that is called by mongoose when accessing a geoJSON property.

My Mongoose schema is set up like so

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  location: {
    type: { type: String },
    coordinates: [],
  },
})
userSchema.index({ location: '2dsphere' });
```

Attempted to try this without the extra assignment as well running the query simply as

```
location: { $near: { $geometry: loggedin.location } },
```

But got the same error.

Another interesting fact is if I drop into the native client with `mongoose.models.Users.collection` and execute my query I don't receive the error at all.

[Sample gist with mongo shell output and native query](https://gist.github.com/RobAWilkinson/8482c5710bf8c87d4a2f5b9303ca4bb1)

Comment: So what does the `loggedin` document result actually look like? The error would suggest the `location` field is not actually a valid "geometry" value and is probably just a  "string". This is probably due to the defined `Schema` being incorrect in the first place. So you probably should be showing us the `Schema` as well.

Comment: I have it in mongoose like 
`location: {
    type: { type: String },
    coordinates: [],
  },
`
And i set the index at the bottom with `userSchema.index({ location: '2dsphere' });`

Comment: You should show the document, since the error would indicate that the data is not in fact in that format. Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36818391/edit) link on your question to add additional details. And comments just to notify of the change.

Comment: updated question with a snippet of the data and also another factor

Comment: It's probably "too small" a "snippet". I think you are actually "sanitizing" the real object content. What **I** really want to se is one document as it would appear in the [`mongo` "shell"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/)  output without any changes. That I think will shed some light on this. The `.lean()` point is interesting, but the "whole document" in context ( and **not** mongoose output ) will be the most telling thing.

Comment: awesome I can definitely do that, its pretty massive is it appropriate to link a gist/pastebin?

Comment: Arf! Actually it should be pretty obvious but I just wasn't seeing it that way. Just try directly using `{ location: { "$near": { "$geometry": loggedin.location } } }` in the query. This "should" be basically an artifact that a mongoose document is **not** a plain JavaScript object. And therefore the assignment does not do what you think it is doing. Without a conversion to `.lean()` first. But just as `loggedin.location` directly it should be fine. If not then give a gist.pastebin link.

Comment: same result without the extra assignment, added a link to the native query and a sample of the mongo shell output

Comment: I eventually had a look at this using your data and at least a partially defined schema, and it does not reproduce. At least not on `mongoose.4.4.13`. You might want to check the version in use and possibly upgrade.

Comment: I"m at 4.0.3 right now, thanks for the help anyways. I'll try to set up isolated test case at some point and file an issue if it still persists

Answer (score 0):

Try out through this code

```
 $geoNear: {
            near: {type: "Point", coordinates:[parseFloat(req.query.latitude), parseFloat(req.query.longitude )]},
            distanceField: "dist.calculated",
            maxDistance:10000,
            spherical: true
        }
```